# Does there exist a process to build a list of numbers whose standard deviation is an integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, st.statistics, computer-science

Or rephrased, is there a way to make a list of numbers whose sample variance is a square number? I'm interested in sequences of arbitrary length with integer elements.

(I come from a computer science background so my apologies if this question is a poor one).

Comment: I've run into this problem in trying to come up with exercises in statistics classes where the arithmetic will work out nicely.  If you're interested in small lists of short integers, one way is to just pick random lists and compute their standard deviations.

Comment: I guess brute force is always an option :)

Comment: I guess 0 is always an option.

Comment: George, are you using the sample variance formula where you divide by $n$, or the one where you divide by $n-1$?

Comment: Sample variance corresponds with $n-1$ doesn't it?

Comment: Different sources give different definitions, George. $n-1$ is OK by me.

Answer (score 7):

Essentially, this problem is to generate integers $n,s,a_1,\dots,a_n$ such that $n\ge1$ and
$$(n-1)s^2=a_1^2+\dots+a_n^2.\tag{1}$$
To do this, let $k:=\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ and take any nonnegative integers $t_1,\dots,t_k$ such that
$$(n-1)s^2=t_1+\dots+t_k.\tag{2}$$
For each $j\in[k]:=\{1,\dots,k\}$, by [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem), there exist integers $a_{j1},\dots,a_{j4}$ such that
$$t_j=\sum_{i=1}^4 a_{ji}^2,$$
so that
$$(n-1)s^2=\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^4 a_{ji}^2.\tag{3}$$
The latter expression is the sum of $4k\le n$ squares of nonnegative integers. Complementing this sum by the sum of $n-4k$ squares of $0$, we get representation (1) -- for any given natural $n$ and integer $s$.

---

This is illustrated by the the following image of a Mathematica notebook, finding a representation (1) for $n=15$ and $s=5$;
$$(15-1)5^2=4^2 + 0^2 + 8^2 + 6^2 + 10^2 + 0^2 + 4^2 + 2^2 + 5^2 + 0^2 + 8^2 + 
 5^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 + 0^2.$$

[image]

---

Of course, the $a_i$'s in (1) are the deviations of the sample values from the sample mean. Previously, I forgot to take into account that the sum of the $a_i$'s must of course be $0$.

$\newcommand\ep\epsilon$One way to get that is to try to attach "signs" $\ep_i\in\{-1,1\}$ to the $a_i$'s so that $\sum_{i=1}^m\ep_i a_i=0$. I think usually this will be possible to do when $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i$ is even, as is the case with the above example (continued below). Otherwise, repeat with other $t_1,\dots,t_k$ in (2) and/or with other instances of the $a_{j1},\dots,a_{j4}$'s.

[image]

The problem of the existence of "balancing" signs $\ep_i\in\{-1,1\}$ is obviously equivalent to the so-called [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is easily solved for not too big values $n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i$ in view of the [simple recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Recurrence_relation), whose application to the particular $a_i$'s considered in the mentioned Mathematica notebook is illustrated here:

[image]

This again confirms that for our particular $a_i$'s "balancing" signs $\ep_i\in\{-1,1\}$ exist.

The problem of actually finding an appropriate partition (which is equivalent to finding "balancing" signs $\ep_i\in\{-1,1\}$) was solved by [Korf](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271585/1-s2.0-S0004370200X00471/1-s2.0-S0004370298000861/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEN3%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQD53CYmLSRvIY2uv6Tz23Ib9F2P2nKLYIAqW0WkqL90fgIgBYLjAXUY%2BkIsg%2FuP0Ez%2BO7KNVffhHwGHVB1oTAcMSR8qtAMIRhADGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDKYxDHR3juqfP8d3syqRA5%2B80Q8uIrMc685apSjjKX%2BRv96dkHedBU%2Fpjx5t7jgfzrCxmvZWzUxMqLFRRgGwKGH0X0k6ayLlfb1GNQBbTdQ%2BhiJuK6gXLJg6bACY5OOojGLDdG2iqnJWMgSfdDxuzezz4QpQCfWuz8g5GNBBl0pBeHE5wB6ku7a6uCaqGcvuWZ4IAk0GmBWiOees7BGcwltd6lRn%2FPZd8%2BrJOI5BBa0MmnSZ4Tz3ougDnjz3WHsX27TvP%2FazS%2F2n9KldsmMh9lrU%2FIkTaLMTULOh0x7toIhrH4qatVFY%2FJuDTYn0E8vfEkslhV7dUEkH6Lr6e5x7Azy8B9bvH84wsGSjKwIYIq4mMiuQ%2FgQTfxPvcL0fzvQwDYFgl%2FcYPofPOHj9lhnLPRoqbDZxeTzeBm6AJuJsIGNXh8xSweJBUxn%2FmwrtyeIGiiCl16Rvvcr0Q8LTWF3EadOZW55G2f5gunMhh3uiYUNnQR4VSeVwXmaA6NzHhAgBSwxrVDWMWpIrvGAkfC28WUsKEvEg%2BlS1B%2FxgWMJ8SzhmMLvLn%2F0FOusByRrge55RZjaKwZJ3i%2BI616e89Mo2hKr76zD63SvmFLufqgwVGh6zeXzB0vDBq29vjq7iY4zZCs7J29f8VuI3PKREuz0SozKnXHVf0B5FZtkVA0QkCDO%2Bz4%2BEFzfZ97YoRz2lvlABYtQLgj3UAPWLsZmlIlTdoVA0VcUqEZds8ASjkaw2rDKO6KXJP7QnZhATtdiz96HbRJT5XsEjzTJGFATS3lsxrBCeTZ%2BDMdLmKULBikZixO1dVZpUIAVpu86%2FNIPuWdDmZ7mznIpVG%2BObwm9B%2FSGJwxDQZHdZUqRXS9SAo%2Bt8lwHjVItXFQ%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201108T130117Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4DKKBKPU%2F20201108%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=2d94d90b013321ac53609062d82fee4c1efe65f298a4f20424e956ce0b922317&hash=f8e5a0028cc8702b5d8d85965e4870b1b9c0bf38ecb71179d576afaf07c4ef52&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0004370298000861&tid=spdf-bb85137e-e242-48bc-ad5e-ac4ba2fc88ad&sid=ea8693107648754d967b4681ff962a2d800bgxrqa&type=client).

For our particular $a_i$'s there actually are $18$ different "balancing" sign assignments $(\ep_i)$, not counting sign assignments to the $0$'s.

---

Another way to make the sum of the deviations $0$ is as follows. If $(n-1)s^2$ is even, find integers $b_1,\dots,b_{4l}$ such that
$$(n-1)s^2/2=b_1^2+\dots+b_{4l}^2$$
(cf. (3)), where $l:=\lfloor n/8\rfloor$. Then, letting
$$(a_1,\dots,a_n):=(b_1,\dots,b_{4l},-b_1,\dots,-b_{4l},0,\dots,0),$$
we have both (1) and the balance condition $\sum_{i\in[n]}a_i=0$ satisfied. Of course, one can also replace $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ by any permutation of this $n$-tuple.

Comment: Modulo arithmetical errors, the sequence $4,0,8,6,10,0,4,2,5,0,8,5,0,0,0$ has $n=15$, $A=\Sigma x_i=52$, $B=\Sigma x_i^2=350$ and sample variance $(1/14)(B-(1/15)A^2)=1003/105$ (or, using a different formula, $(1/15)(B-(1/15)A^2)=2546/225$), not an integer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : At the end of the second line in your comment, should the numerator of the fraction be 1273 rather than 1003 ? Anyway, it's still not an integer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : Thank you for your comment. I have now tried to address it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, given rational numbers $u_1,\dotsc,u_n$ you can define $v=\sum_iu_i^2$ and $w_i=2u_i/(1+v)$ for $i\leq n$ and $w_{n+1}=(1-v)/(1+v)$.  Then the numbers $w_j$ are rational with $\sum_jw_j^2=1$.  By clearing denominators you get an equation $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}a_j^2=b^2$ in integers.

Comment: But you want that last sum to come to $nb^2$, not $b^2$, no?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson. Or $(n-1)b^2$ I thought was agreed on...

Comment: @Yaakov I'm happy either way. It seems OP had $n-1$ in mind.